# What are the differences between heap and red-black tree?

Tags: data-structures, heap, red-black-tree

We know that heaps and red-black tree both have these properties:

1. worst-case cost for searching is lgN;
2. worst-case cost for insertion is lgN.

So, since the implementation and operation of red-black trees is difficult, why don't we just use heaps instead of red-black trees? I am confused.

Comment: Would you share the algorithm for `O(log(N))` search in heaps?

Comment: As I remembered, you cannot search in heaps in `O(log(N))`.

Comment: We don't know "first property".

Answer (score 16):

You can't find an arbitrary element in a heap in `O(log n)`. It takes `O(n)` to do this. You can find the first element (the smallest, say) in a heap in `O(1)` and *extract* it in `O(log n)`. Red-black trees and heaps have quite different uses, internal orderings, and implementations: see below for more details.

**Typical use**

Red-black tree: storing dictionary where as well as lookup you want elements sorted by key, so that you can for example iterate through them in order. Insert and lookup are `O(log n)`.

Heap: priority queue (and heap sort). Extraction of minimum and insertion are `O(log n)`.

**Consistency constraints imposed by structure**

Red-black tree: total ordering: left child < parent < right child.

Heap: dominance: parent < children only.

(note that you can substitute a more general ordering than <)

**Implementation / Memory overhead**

Red-black tree: pointers used to represent structure of tree, so overhead per element. Typically uses a number of nodes allocated on free store (e.g. using `new` in C++), nodes point to other nodes. Kept balanced to ensure logarithmic lookup / insertion.

Heap: structure is implicit: root is at position 0, children of root at 1 and 2, etc, so no overhead per element. Typically just stored in a single array.

Answer (score 1):

Red Black Tree:
Form of a binary search tree with a deterministic balancing strategy. This Balancing guarantees good performance and it can always be searched in O(log n) time.

Heaps:
We need to search through every element in the heap in order to determine if an element is inside. Even with optimization, I believe search is still O(N). On the other hand, It is best for finding min/max in a set O(1).